# qt5 is tearing while trying to visualize a geant4 simulation

Tags: qt5, geant4

I am trying to run simulations using Geant4 and I am using qt5 as the GUI. When I started it was working fine but it has started doing this weird screen tearing thing and it makes it impossible to work. Any ideas? I am using qt5-default. I had use qt set to true on the config settings for geant4. I am doing this with wsl2 in ubuntu.  [What the Display looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ox3.png)

I've restarted my computer, uninstalled and reinstalled qt5, and have rebuilt geant4 and nothing has worked so far.

[EDIT] I didn't do anything different but one day it just started working, if this problem happens to anyone else I would just recommend uninstalling Qt5 and reinstalling it and restarting your computer. I'm sorry I can't give better advice than that unfortunately because I am not sure what happened to fix it.